# remove item from pagerView android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

first this is my Activity

```
public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

     viewpager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    swipeadapter = new swipeadapter(this);

    viewpager.setAdapter(swipeadapter);


    //some condition remove textview or hide textview from current Pagerview
    //position 
    //if(mm = oo){ //remove item from current pagerView adapter }




}
}
```

and this my adapter code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

import ws.design.com.R;


public class swipeadapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private LinearLayout player;
SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<>();


    public swipeadapter(Context c){
        this.ctx = c;

    }



    public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
        return registeredFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return (view == (LinearLayout)o);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        registeredFragments.remove(position);
        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
    }

    public void changeVisiblityOfTextView(int visiblity)
    {
        player.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }



    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View inflatedView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.player, container,false);
        player = (LinearLayout)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.buttons);

        Display display =  ((Activity)ctx).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        final Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);








        container.addView(inflatedView);
        return inflatedView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 10;
    }

    void setSimpleList(ListView listView){

        ArrayList<String> contactsList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
            contactsList.add("I am @ index " + index + " today " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());
        }

        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ctx,
                R.layout.fb_comments_list_item, android.R.id.text1,contactsList));
    }
}
```

i have pagerView and its work currently good but i want to hide item in current PagerView position thats shown to user if condition true how can i hide textView with id hideThis from this activity Main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `SparseArray` in your `ViewPager`'s adapter to keep fragment instances like below:

```
SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<>();
```

Note: Why SparseArray? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html

Override `instanstiateItem` method of your `FragmentPagerAdapter` like below:

```
   @Override
   public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
      Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
      registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
      return fragment;
   }
```

And override `DestroyItem` method:

```
@Override
   public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
      registeredFragments.remove(position);
      super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
   }
```

Define a method to get current fragment like below:

```
public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
      return registeredFragments.get(position);
   }
```

Define a public method to change visibility of your `TextViews` in `Fragments`if your condition is `True`

```
public void changeVisiblityOfTextView(int visiblity)
{
    mTextView.setVisiblity(visibility);
}
```

Add a new onPageChangeListener to your `ViewPager`:

```
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                   YourFragment fragment =        (YourFragment)yourPagerAdapter.getRegisteredFragment(position);
                   if(yourCondition){
                      fragment.changeVisiblityOfTextview(View.VISIBLE);
                   }
                   else{
                      fragment.changeVisiblityOfTextView(View.GONE)
                   }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                }
            });
```

I hope my answer helps you. Good Luck!

**Edit:**

**YourPagerAdapter:** FragmentPagerAdapter or FragmentStatePagerAdapter which you set to view pager.

**YourFragment:** It's your custom fragment which you extend from `Support.Fragment` and use in your view pager. (Fragment which you return in your adapter's `public Fragment getItem(int position)` method.

It's basically you add your fragment instances in a sparse array when you init return a new fragment in your view pager and get it to from adapter to change visibility of items which you put in your fragment.

I assume that your textview's in your view pager fragment's layout.

**Edit 2:**

Ops you do not use Fragments in your ViewPager so my solution is not suitable for you. You can change your ViewPager implementation to fragments or instead of keeping fragments in sparse array you can keep your inflated views which you add to container and instead of fragments you can go on with that views. And in onPageChanged method you can get view as in my example, find your textview and change it's visibility.

When i have time i'll add code here.

Comment: but how can i call this changeVisiblityOfTextview from Main_activity because the condition in Main_activity

Comment: if your view pager is in your main activity than the onpagechange listener code is in your main activity.

Comment: ok but when i add it in main activity YourFragment  be undefined :/

Comment: just explain to me YourFragment its undefined in Main_activity  what you mean with it

Comment: i will edit my question please check it after edit done

Comment: i edit it and add my adapter code problem now in YourFragment i dont know how to use it in Main_activity  in undefined

Comment: its work after i change my adapter to FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: :) :) :) :) :)  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove an item from your `ViewPager`, you need to remove it from the `PagerAdapter` and call `notifyDatasetChanged()` then set the adapter to the `ViewPager` again:

```
mAdapter.removeItem(position);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

You need to add a `removeItem` method in your adapter class (or however you want to remove the item):

```
public class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    //...

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        if (position > -1 && position < items.size()) {
            items.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    } 

    //...
}
```

This is the only way I got the `ViewPager` to refresh and fully remove the view in question.

You can store the current `ViewPager` position just before you remove the item and set the `ViewPager` to that position again.